# Running existing react js app

Tags: reactjs

When i am running existing react js app, it stuck here

```
fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
Building for undefined
 10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 active                                         
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
404s will fallback to /index.html
 95% emittingTotal precache size is about 0 B for 0 resources.                             
 95% emittingTotal precache size is about 0 B for 0 resources.
```

it is not showing any error and for this app is not running on browser.
Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment:  are you sure it is a react app not an angular app ?

Comment: Yes i am sure and i run it from Ubuntu. I also tried from windows but nothing happened after this few lines.

Answer (score -1):

This may happen due to service workers configured in the app. If you are using webpack,please comment [SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/goldhand/sw-precache-webpack-plugin)